# Send and receive Json, cant read the response

Tags: c#, json

I'm creating a application, and in one of it's functionalities I need to send json code over web request.

I use Get, Post, Put and Delete. And I already can create the connection and send and receive data.

But, for every request I should receive json code. Which I believe I am receiving, but I can't read it...

I'l put some code sample so you can see if there is something I can make to read that json code

First the Get request:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (this.getURL ());
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";

var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse ();

var responseString = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ()).ReadToEnd ();
webRequest.Abort();

return JArray.Parse (responseString);
```

This is the only case where I can read the json answer.

Next Post request:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (this.getURL ());
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";

var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream ();

stream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close ();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
webRequest.Abort();

return (int)response.StatusCode;
```

In this example I solved my problem using the response code.. which can only be 200, because every other code Is assumed as some exception.

For put and delete will be the same as post. 
As I said I need to receive the json code. and not only the response code.

I would be really grateful if you could help-me in this problem.

Comment: Response code can be different from 200 and still be valid response. Is it possible the server just always return HTML when posting to it ?

Comment: That server has a platform were you can see the url's to use and which data you should send or which answer to expect. and In that platform It works just fine. I get that json code that I need... 
And I believe that the problem is in my code, because I receive the json code when I use GET. and I've seen another application working with this platform and I know for a fact that U can receive that json code....

Comment: Can you post the URL and form data that needed to be sent for both GET and POST actions ?

Comment: I can sample that...

the url is https://some.app.com:9999/rest/public/version/action?userKey&parameters=value

and the data is diferent for every action so in this case it should be:

{
    "status" : "ok",
    "id" : "value"
}

the answere to POST is an array of those previous json objects

but this isn't relevant in this problem... since I can already receive data.. I just can´t read'it properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Orel who tried do help.

I got mt problem solved, I will post a sample code for everyone who might need this kind of solution.

My problem actually was very simple. 
When I used "POST" in a web request I would create a stream to actually post my data. And then I would try to get my answer from that same stream, when actually I was getting the information I needed In the webRequest var.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (this.getURL ());
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";

var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream ();

stream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);

var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

stream.Close ();webRequest.Abort();

return JObject.Parse(responseString);
```